# Scrabble drag technique

Tags: objective-c, ios, touch, puzzle

I had created an puzzle game which was like Scrabble.

Here is the layout:

1    2    3    4

5    6    7    8

9   10   11    12

13  14   15    16

What is my problem?

My problem was when I start touch from 1 and direction to 12, If touch and drag in slow then no problem but when drag in fast, I manage to 1, 6, 12 or 1, 7, 12 only. There is missing a number.

How to make sure the path numbers all be selected?

I am using `touch began`, `touch moved` and `touch ended` and check with coordinate to locate which number is being touched.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.numberview];
if(!ispause && [time.text intValue] > 0){
    if(!isbegan && !isended){
        for(int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        {
            UIView *imageview = [self.numberview viewWithTag:i];
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageview.frame, currentTouchLocation))
            {
                isbegan = YES;
                isreverse = NO;
                if([[ischose objectAtIndex:i-1] boolValue] == 0)
                {
                    currentposition = imageview.tag;
                    positionvalue += pow(i, 3);
                    currentanswer += [self converter:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [allimagenumbers substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i-1, 1)]]];
                    [ischose replaceObjectAtIndex:i-1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
                    [self changeimage:@"selected"];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.numberview];

float gapX = image1.frame.size.width / 8;
float gapY = image1.frame.size.height / 8;

if(isbegan && !isended)
{
    if(currentTouchLocation.x >= 0 && currentTouchLocation.x <= self.numberview.frame.size.width && currentTouchLocation.y >= 0 && currentTouchLocation.y <= self.numberview.frame.size.height)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        {
            UIView *imageview = [self.numberview viewWithTag:i];
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageview.frame, currentTouchLocation))
            {
                if((currentTouchLocation.x >= imageview.frame.origin.x + gapX && currentTouchLocation.x < imageview.frame.origin.x + imageview.frame.size.width  - gapX) && (currentTouchLocation.y >= imageview.frame.origin.y  + gapY && currentTouchLocation.y < imageview.frame.origin.y + imageview.frame.size.height - gapY ))
                {
                    if([[ischose objectAtIndex:i-1] boolValue] == 0 && !isreverse)
                    {
                        currentposition = imageview.tag;
                        positionvalue += pow(i, 3);
                        currentanswer += [self converter:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [allimagenumbers substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i-1, 1)]]];
                        [ischose replaceObjectAtIndex:i-1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
                        [self changeimage:@"selected"];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(currentposition != imageview.tag)
                        {
                            isreverse = YES;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            isreverse = NO;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isended = YES;
        isoutofbound = YES;
        if(isbegan && isoutofbound)
            [self countinganswer];
    }
}
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
if(!isoutofbound)
{
    isended = YES;
    [self countinganswer];
}
else
    isoutofbound = NO;
}

-(void)changeimage:(NSString *)status{
if([status isEqualToString:@"default"])
{
    for(int i = 1; i <=16;i++)
    {
        UIImageView *imageview = (UIImageView*)[self.numberview viewWithTag:i];
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"stone%@", [allimagenumbers substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i-1, 1)]]];
        [image1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
}
else if([status isEqualToString:@"correct"] || [status isEqualToString:@"selected"])
{
    for(int i = 1; i<= ischose.count; i++)
    {
        if([[ischose objectAtIndex:i-1] boolValue] == 1)
        {
            UIImageView *imageview = (UIImageView*)[self.numberview viewWithTag:i];
            imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"stone%@_correct", [allimagenumbers substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i-1, 1)]]];
        }
    }
}
else if([status isEqualToString:@"wrong"] || [status isEqualToString:@"repeat"])
{
    for(int i = 1; i<= ischose.count; i++)
    {
        if([[ischose objectAtIndex:i-1] boolValue] == 1)
        {
            UIImageView *imageview = (UIImageView*)[self.numberview viewWithTag:i];
            imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"stone%@_wrong_repeat", [allimagenumbers substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i-1, 1)]]];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I suspect that your answer will be closed as "not constructive" unless you show some code and narrow down your question. Personally, I'd suggest consider checking out [Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1) such as `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. It makes dragging easier in my opinion. But you haven't shown enough for anyone to diagnose why your current solution is "slow" or "missing a number."

Comment: i tried pan gesture, but it was same

Comment: Then you have to show us code and/or share more details about your implementation. Many of us do dragging without any problem at all. Possible problems might include if you're doing computationally expensive stuff like a `CALayer` shadow (in which case you can address with `shouldRasterize`) or some inefficiency in your code. But you haven't shared nearly enough for anyone to make intelligent suggestions about possible fixes. The only other suggestion is to use the Instruments tool to profile your app and examine where the most CPU time is being spent.

Comment: If nothing else, you could dramatically simplify your code by using `CGRectContainsPoint`, e.g. `CGRectContainsPoint(image1.frame, currentTouchLocation)`, rather than the whole series of nested if statements. But still looking at your code, but perhaps you can describe what you're trying to do. It doesn't look like you're dragging anything. Are you just trying to track the user's finger and identify what number they're over?

Comment: yup, because the 16 numbers image is stick together, i want to narrow down the intersect point which is the 3/4 of whole image size. When I drag fast, I can detect first and last number, if I drag from 1 to direction 8, the number 1, 2, 7, 8 or 1, 6, 7, 8 will be touched but result shown only 1, 2, 8 or 1, 8 only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19741/discussion-between-rob-and-alan-lai)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Chatting with you, it appears that you have solved your problem (where a swipe over one of your `UIImageView` objects was not being detected). It looks like the solution was a unique issue (i.e. highly "localized" in Stack Overflow language) associated with your code to create reduced size "hit zones" that you constructed with your `gap` variables. It doesn't look like the solution was anything really associated with `touchesMoved`, iOS API, or iOS system performance. Regardless, I'm glad you solved the problem.

My original answer below was predicated on the original source code posted, which had the same logic repeated for each of the 16 `UIImageView` objects. I was just demonstrating how you can use a `UIArray` to significantly simplify that logic. I also use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, which I think unifies the code, and with `<UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>` you can cancel the gesture, in case the user's gesture went "out of bounds."

---

**Original answer:**

I'm assuming that you simply want to build an array of image numbers as the user drags their finger over the numbers. So the ARC code might look something like:

```
//  NumberGameViewController.m

#import "NumberGameViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@interface NumberGameViewController ()
{
    NSArray *images;
    NSMutableArray *results;
}
@end

@implementation NumberGameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // if you build an array of your images, the logic to determine which image you're over is much easier

    images = @[self.image1, self.image2, self.image3, self.image4, self.image5, self.image6, self.image7, self.image8, self.image9, self.image10, self.image11, self.image12, self.image13, self.image14, self.image15, self.image16];

    // I know you used `touchesMoved` and the like, but I think gesture recognizers are a little easier

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [self.numberview addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}

- (NSInteger)determineImageNumber:(CGPoint)point
{
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [images count]; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *imageview = images[i];

        // I'm just going to see if the user's finger was over the number in question.
        // If you wanted more restrictive logic (e.g. 3/4ths of the frame), just adjust
        // adjust the frame variable here. 

        CGRect frame = imageview.frame;
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, point))
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self.numberview];
    NSInteger imageNumber = [self determineImageNumber:location];
    static NSInteger lastImageNumber;

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if (imageNumber >= 0)
        {
            [results addObject:@(imageNumber)];
        }
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        if (imageNumber >= 0)
        {
            if (imageNumber != lastImageNumber)
            {
                // If you want to do some visual adjustment of the image you're over, do it
                // here.

                // add the image to our array of results

                [results addObject:@(imageNumber)];

                // if you want to do some additional validation (e.g. do you have 16 points,
                // has the user hit the same number twice, etc.), do that here
            }
        }

        // by the way, let's check to see if we're still within the numberview subview, and if
        // not, let's cancel the gesture

        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(self.numberview.bounds, location))
        {
            gesture.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled;
            return;
        }
    }
    else if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) || (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) || (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed))
    {
        // At this point you'd do any final validation of the user's response, to see if they
        // succeeded or not. I'm just displaying the results in the console

        NSLog(@"%@", results);
    }

    if (imageNumber >= 0)
        lastImageNumber = imageNumber;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float gapX = image1.frame.size.width / 8;
float gapY = image1.frame.size.height / 8;
```

Here is the problem, there is a gap within all images so when fast drag it will be outer part of images